# getting File from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm implementing export to csv in MVC.
Since the parameters are datetime types I need to send the data in post because of user different cultures.

Server Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<FileResult> ExportBomTotal(ReportRequestVM reportRequestVM)
{
    List<MyData> result = await service.getData(reportRequestVM);
    string fileName = string.Format("file{0}-{1} .csv", reportRequestVM.StartDate.ToShortDateString(), reportRequestVM.EndDate.ToShortDateString());
    return new CSVResult<MyData>(result) { FileDownloadName = fileName };
}
```

And in the client I'm trying to send the data in post like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportBomTotal", "Analytics")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(searchParameters),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
    //  window.location.assign(data);
    // window.location.replace(data);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        debugger;
    },
    cache: false
});
```

The dates are passed to the server, so far this is fine, but I can't get the download file popup.
I guess that I need to use the window.location but the request is required to be post operation.

For those how asked for CSVResult
 public sealed class CSVResult : FileResult
        where T : class
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable _collection;

```
    public CSVResult(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base("text/csv")
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
        using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteObject(mstream);
            outputStream.Write(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mstream.Length);
        }
    }

    private void WriteObject(Stream stream)
    {
        // We will follow the recommandations stated in this article
        // http://www.commentcamarche.net/faq/sujet-7273-exporter-a-coup-sur-du-csv
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        //modelType.
        Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

        // Render columns
        Type modelType = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo[] props = modelType.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (VisibleAttribute visible in attrs.OfType<VisibleAttribute>())
            {
                dict.Add(prop.Name, visible.Hide);
            }
        }
        List<ModelMetadata> metadatas = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperties(null, modelType)
            .Where(m => !dict.ContainsKey(m.PropertyName) || dict[m.PropertyName] )
                .OrderBy(p => p.Order).ToList();

        foreach (ModelMetadata t in metadatas)
        {
            WriteValue(writer, t.DisplayName ?? t.PropertyName);
        }

        writer.WriteLine();
        // Render data
        var en = _collection.GetEnumerator();
        while (en.MoveNext())
        {
            ModelMetadata mprop = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => en.Current, modelType);

            var allowedProperties = mprop.Properties
                .Where(m => !dict.ContainsKey(m.PropertyName) || dict[m.PropertyName]);
            foreach (ModelMetadata prop in allowedProperties)
            {
                WriteValue(writer, prop.SimpleDisplayText ?? String.Empty);
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
        writer.Flush();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The writer.</param>
    /// <param name="literal">The literal.</param>
    private static void WriteValue(StreamWriter writer, String literal)
    {
        // Enclose values in quote
        writer.Write("\"");
        string line = literal;//.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
        writer.Write(line);
        writer.Write("\",");
    }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated,
1o,
Rony

Comment: Could you show us the class CSVResult?

Comment: What MVC version are you using ?

Comment: the file is long but the idea of using reflection on the Type and print it to the stream.

Comment: Kenneth: I put the code you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You can't force a browser to *download* data that you have received by an ajax call already.

If you really have to post the data, you can submit a form with javascript to trigger your download action.

If a get is sufficient, you can just assign `location.href` with the link of your download action.

**EDIT: Form example**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportBomTotal", "Analytics") {

   ... render your searchparameters as html inputs

}

// submit the form with javascript:
$('form').submit();
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for your quick replay, but how can u use location.href in post operation ?

Comment: @ron just like you would in a form submit. `location.href = targetlocation`. your service would have to return what `targetlocation` is, meaning your file would need to be accessible via a GET url.

Comment: thanks Kevin B, but the problem is that the action is required to be in port operation. because client are passing datetime.

Comment: I know that get would solve this problem, but I'm working with multiple cultures hence post operation is required.

Comment: @ron When posting, you won't set location.href. You just create a plain html form and submit that to your action. I update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't get the download file popup

That's normal. You cannot use AJAX to download files. The success call back of your AJAX request will be executed and passed as data argument the CSV generated file that you could manipulate on the client but you cannot prompt with any Save As dialogs.

If you want to achieve this you should provide a standard HTML form containing the required parameters whose submission you could trigger using javascript. As an alternative if you don't have many parameters you could use a standard anchor pointing to the controller action.